# SQL command to retrieve data in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a tableadapter with  { id, Place, MD, KVC } and I want to retrieve data depending on place

```
select [Id], [MD], [KVC] 
from tbl 
where [place] = ?
```

I have different places, for example: Canada, France, Germany , England ..etc

What I want is to get the data that are not related to Canada for example.
Which means all data related to France, Germany and England ..etc

How to reemphasize the SQL command or query to achieve that?

Comment: `[place]<>?` Use not equals to `<>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use not equals to `<>`

```
select [Id],[MD],[KVC] from tbl where [place]<>?
```

And pass in `Canada` as the value of the parameter.

---

> and what if i want to retrieve England and Germany

```
select [Id],[MD],[KVC] from tbl where [place]=? OR [place]=?
```

And pass in `England` as the value of the first parameter and `Germany` as the value of the second parameter.

Comment: and what if i want to retrieve England and Germany
select [Id],[MD],[KVC] from tbl where [place]<>?  and [place] <>? 
will this work ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `WHERE place IN (?, ?)`? :)

Comment: @JohnyL - They would yield the same result so it would be equivalent and it comes down to a matter of preference. If there are just 2 values you want to filter on I prefer what I have above. If the number of values grows to more than that or if the number of values can vary depending on what the user is choosing then my preference would also be `IN`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Igor's answer, you could generalize query for any number of parameters with [IN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql):

```
SELECT Id, MD, KVC
FROM   tbl 
WHERE  place IN (?, ?, ?);
```